# R: How to convert a string to a list variable in for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop

I am doing a number of regression's using a for loop, and want to store the results in a list. Normally, I would use assign:

```
AllChicks <- levels(ChickWeight$Chick) #example database

for (i in AllChicks) {
  DataSub <- subset(ChickWeight, Chick==i)
  Fit <- lm(DataSub$Time ~ DataSub$weight)
  assign(paste("Regr_",i,sep=""),Fit)
  assign(paste("Sum_",i,sep=""),summary(Fit))
  assign(paste("Residual_",i,sep=""),residuals(Fit))
}
```

But now i would like to put the Fit, summary and Residuals in a list per Chick, so named Chick1, Chick2, Chick3 etc.
I have found the following commands to work for the first object:

```
assign(paste("Chick",i,sep=""),list(Fit))
do.call("<-",list(paste("Chick",i,sep=""),list(Fit)))
```

But then off course the first list object is overwritten by:

```
assign(paste("Chick",i,sep=""),list(summary(Fit)))
```

And I've tried these, but they make a variable named "Chick1[[2]]", in stead of taking the second object from the list.

```
assign(paste("Chick",i,"[[2]]",sep=""),list(summary(Fit)))
do.call("<-",list(paste("Chick",i,"[[2]]",sep=""),list(summary(Fit))))
```

I have a feeling it must be very simple, but can't figure it out...

Comment: look at dominus approach. It is better to use a list behaviour rather than spoiling the global envrionment with tones of variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using `lapply` and `split` which will return a list with one element per chick and each chick-element in the list is itself a list with three components: the model, model summary and residuals.

```
res <- lapply(split(ChickWeight, paste0("Chick", ChickWeight$Chick)), function(x) {
  Fit <- lm(x$Time ~ x$weight)
  list(
    Regr = Fit,
    Sum = summary(Fit),
    Residual = residuals(Fit)
  )
})
```

---

Now, to look at the results, e.g. for "Chick1" you can do:

```
> res$Chick1
$Regr

Call:
lm(formula = x$Time ~ x$weight)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)     x$weight  
     -2.487        0.120  


$Sum

Call:
lm(formula = x$Time ~ x$weight)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.5545 -1.1895  0.2818  1.3340  1.7635 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -2.486826   0.980399  -2.537   0.0295 *  
x$weight     0.120031   0.007868  15.255 2.97e-08 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.507 on 10 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9588,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9547 
F-statistic: 232.7 on 1 and 10 DF,  p-value: 2.974e-08


$Residual
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7 
-2.55448776 -1.63476925 -0.59501946  0.80482416  1.36444885  1.32391715  1.76351056 
          8           9          10          11          12 
 1.48291632  0.60216569 -0.03852238 -1.39939812 -1.11958577
```

Or, if you want to get only the residuals of chick1, you can do:

```
> res$Chick1$Residual
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7 
-2.55448776 -1.63476925 -0.59501946  0.80482416  1.36444885  1.32391715  1.76351056 
          8           9          10          11          12 
 1.48291632  0.60216569 -0.03852238 -1.39939812 -1.11958577
```

---

Edit after comment:

I never work with `assign` so I won't suggest any use of it here either but if you want to use a `for` loop, you could do it like this (or somehow similar):

```
chicks <- unique(ChickWeight$Chick)
res <- vector("list", length = length(chicks))

for(i in chicks) {
  DataSub <- ChickWeight[ChickWeight$Chick == i, ]
  Fit <- lm(DataSub$Time ~ DataSub$weight)
  res[[i]] <- list(
    Regr = Fit,
    Sum = summary(Fit),
    Residual = residuals(Fit)
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you (and +1) for this elegant, R-ish answer. However, i would still like to know if there is a way to fill a list by assign or do.call in a for loop. Or is that impossible?